# Proof that the set of all square summable sequences is a metric space under this distance

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Here is a portion of my paper I am currently writing for real analysis part 2. My question is, can I change the summations from $i=1 \rightarrow \infty$ to $i=1 \rightarrow n$ using the definition? This part of the proof is bolded. I am unsure if I am able to do this; my motivation is I want to apply minkowsky's inequality and Cauchy's inequality to prove the triangle inequality here (just like the euclidean metric) but I need the summation to be finite and not infinite.

The set of all square summable sequences, $l_2=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)|x_n\in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty,$ $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots) | y_n\in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n|^2 < \infty\}$ is a metric space, where the distance $p(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-y_i)^2}$.

Since it has been proven that $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$, it is sufficient to prove the following to satisfy property 3:
\begin{align*}
&p(x,y) \leq p(x,z) + p(z,y). 
\end{align*}
Using the above definitions, we have to show:
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-z_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(z_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}. 
\end{align*}
However, by assumption we know that:
\begin{align*}
l_2=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots) | x_n\in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty\}
\end{align*}
***Since we know that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \infty}$, we can sum from $i=1$ to $n$ instead of from $i=1$ to $\infty$ due to the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-y_i)^2$ is still the sum of square summable sequences since both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are squares. The same holds for $z_n$ and $y_n$.Thus, if we show that this inequality holds true for the summation to $n$, for all values of $n$, we can generalize it to an infinite summation. Thus, we want to show that:***
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-z_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Your statement "we can sum from $1$ to $n$" is completely unjustified. At best, it needs clarification (what is the value of $n$? Are you saying that you can just pick some value of $n$?) and at worst, is completely wrong.

Comment: @5xum I am just trying to use the part of the definition which states that the summation is less than infinity. I want to use this to allow us to take a finite sum and not an infinite sum, in order to use Minkowski and Cauchy's inequality to prove this. I know we are supposed to use these two according to our professor. The $n$ from $l_2$ and the summations are not the same $n$. I might be wrong with what I am doing, but I was thinking that I could not use these two inequalities because we have infinite sums and not finite sums, like the definitions of the inequalities are written.

Comment: But why would the fact that the sum is finite have anything to do with the fact that you can take only a finite number of elements? Also, I ask again, are you saying that you will prove the inequality *for every value of $n$* or do you just select some value of $n$? Right now, it is very unclear what $n$ is equal to.

Comment: @5xum I am sorry for being difficult, I am just having a hard time explaining my thoughts. I am asking that if we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n| < \infty$, and we want to show that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(x_i-z_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(z_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, can we instead show $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-z_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i-y_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: @Frumpy And **What**, I ask again, is the value of $n$?

Comment: @5xum It is not a specific number but rather a finite summation from $1,2,\ldots, n$.

Comment: @Frumpy Yes, I see you are summing from $1$ to $n$. But unless you specify *either* that you will prove your inequality **for every value of $n$** *or* you specify that you will prove it for **some specific value of $n$**, it is completely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @5xum I want to prove this for any value of $n$. By my definition of the distance, I have a summation from $1 \rightarrow \infty$. Now, I want to eventually use the fact that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, but this involves the summations from $i=1 \rightarrow n$. I figured since we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2 < \infty$, we could solve this for the finite summation instead. For some reason the power of 1/2 is not being show on the $b_i$ correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21251/discussion-between-frumpy-and-5xum).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your position. It is only now possible ti answer your question: **Yes**. If you prove your inequality *for all values of $n$*, then you can generalize it to an infinite sumation.

Comment: @5xum Is my logic right, that since that summation of $x_n$ is less than $\infty$, we can do this?

Comment: Well, it isn't because the sum is less than $\infty$. Even if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x|^n$ diverges, your argument would still hold.

Comment: @5xum So instead, I should say that it suffices to show this for all values of $n$ since we can generalize this to an infinite summation. But what is the reasoning behind this? Also, the summation is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2<\infty$ (the one I'm referring to).

Comment: The reasoning behind it is that if $b_n<a_n$ for all values of $n$, then the limit of $b_n$ is smaller or equal to the limit of $a_n$. For this axiom, you do not need the fact that the sum of absolute values converges. You need that fact because otherwise, $p(x,0)$ would not be defined.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me generalize the finite sum to the infinite sum. In my paper I currently have written that, "Thus, if we show that this inequality holds true for the summation to $n$, for all values of $n$, we can generalize it to an infinite summation. So it suffices to show that..." I don't particularly understand where you are getting the $a_n < b_n$.

Comment: Do you agree that for any two convergent sequences, if $a_n\leq b_n$, then $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$?

Comment: @5xum Yes I agree with that statement.

Comment: And do you understant that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_n$$ is defined as $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)?$$

Comment: @5xum do you mean to have $x_i$ and not $x_n$ since you sum from $i=1$? Yes I understand that for the most part.